# Auto increment number in a sequential text

Tags: php, html

is it possible for me to do an auto increment number in a sequential text that can be display in PHP and HTML, for example;

```
SKP/SH/1(AUTO_INCREMENT)/2017
SKP/SH/2/2017
```

Only the number is increase, and the `SKP/SH/""/2017` is fixed.

Thanks in advance, appreciate your help!

**side note:** I already set primary key and auto increment in mysql (separated with 2 column for ID and CODE)

HTML:

```
<form name=b onsubmit="return check()" action="form.php" method="post">
Nama Program: <br />
<textarea required name="program" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea><br />
<p></p>
Tarikh Program Mula: <br />
<input required name="tarikhmula" type="text" class="datepicker">
<p></p>
Tarikh Program Tamat: <br />
<input required name="tarikhtamat" type="text" class="datepicker">
<p></p>
Sebut Harga Bilangan: <br />
<p></p>
Kod Sebut Harga: <br />
<input required name="kodsebutharga" type="text" value="SKP/SH/2017" />
<p></p>
Tarikh Iklan Dibuka: <br />
<input required name="iklanmula" type="text" class="datepicker">
<p></p>
Tarikh Iklan Ditutup: <br />
<input required name="iklantamat" type="text" class="datepicker">
<p></p>
Nama Pegawai Penyelaras: <br />
<input required name="namapegawai" type="text" />
<p></p>
Anggaran Harga Jabatan: <br />
<input required name="anggaranharga" type="text" id="number" pattern="[0-9]*">
<p></p>
<input name="" type="submit" /><input name="" type="reset" value="Clear" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

 require("config.php");
 $link =mysqli_connect($h,$u,$p,$db);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);


 $query = "insert into atas50 (program, tarikhmula, tarikhtamat, namapegawai, anggaranharga, iklanmula, iklantamat) values ('$_POST[program]','$_POST[tarikhmula]','$_POST[tarikhtamat]','$_POST[namapegawai]','$_POST[anggaranharga]','$_POST[iklanmula]','$_POST[iklantamat]')";


 if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    //echo "New record created successfully";
    $message = "New record created successfully";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
    header( "refresh:0; url=view.php" ); 
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $query . "<br>" . mysqli_error($link);
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Short answer: yes. If you have a sequential / auto-increment number in the SQL, just display that number? If that doesn't work (for instance if there are deleted records, and you need a consistent numbering), then just loop the result from the database, and update a counter.

Comment: im sorry i rather new in this field, can you show me? btw i seperated the ID and the code in 2 different column because it seems that i cant put the whole code to auto increment. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (pseudo-code):

```
$counter = 1;
while ($row = fetch_from_database()) {
 echo 'SKP/SH'+$counter+'/2017';
 $counter++;
}
```

Note that this is entirely pseudo-code, and you'll have to implement it as you need.

Comment: hey sorry to trouble you, but can you guide me on how and where can i put this so that it can be displayed in my form.html?

Comment: No, because you haven't provided any code that I can use as a starting point. Update your question with the code, then maybe. But if this is a daunting task, then you really should read up a bit more, maybe do a few tutorials, maybe complete CodeCanyon or something. Basically, you fetch stuff from the database, and you should have a `for()` or `while()` looping through the results you get from the database. That's where you'll include the `$counter`-variable.

Comment: ok wait, argh man my SV really did a number on me. im just an intern and he asked me to do the impossible, wait i'll edit my post.

Comment: Where, exactly, is this incremental number meant to go? First, you said something about repeat content, I can't see any repeat content in that form? Also, if you have an auto-increment column in the database, you don't need to do anything, it will update without adding anything to it... so where, exactly is it you need to have this number?

Comment: Basically like this, whenever a user log in and fill the form the code automatically display the SKP/SH/1/2017 for the first user. Then if a second user fill up the form the code will be SKP/SH/2/2017. I know that my code is wrong and i basically have no idea how to display the increment. The code supposedly will be display on the form WHEN user key in anything in the field provided. In my html code, i hardcoded the `value="SKP/SH/2017"` but my sv doesnt want that, he wants the number to increase but SKP/SH/2017 to be fixed. I know i ask alot but i really need your help. Thanks again